# Create Transform (pie menu and temporary)

Tags: transforms

I can create a custom transform although I do not see how to add it to my pie menu (shortcut key <kbd>,</kbd>)

[image]

[image]

Also, is it possible with shortcut keys to set a temporary custom transform without having to add one as above.

thank you